# I cannot get rid of this space

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have the simple code:

```
answer= input("Have you started your first homework? ")
print("Your answer was:", answer,"!")
```

However every time I run this it prints the answer there is a space before the "!".

I cannot find a way to make the exclamation follow the answer directly. Why and how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print the answer, you have a few options:

```
# Multiple args
print("Your answer was: ", answer, "!", sep="")

# String formatting
print("Your answer was: {}!".format(answer))

# String concatenation
print("Your answer was: " + answer + "!")
```

Python 3.6+:

```
# f-strings
print(f"Your answer was: {answer}!")
```

`print` has an argument called `sep` which, by default, is set to `' '` (a space). It will add that separator between every argument.

Answer (score 1):

`print` function automatically adds a space between comma separated arguments.

So if you don't want that comma, don't pass them as separate arguments and use string formatting instead e.g.:

```
print("Your answer was:", "{}!".format(answer))
```

Here i've concatenated the strings using `str.format`:

```
"{}!".format(answer)
```

If you're in Python 3.6 or later, you can use f-strings:

```
f"{answer}!"
```

You can even use the `printf` style formatting:

```
"%s!" % answer
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print("Your answer was: "+answer"+"!")
```